# Adjusting Bluetooth Speaker Channel

Tags: frequency, bluetooth, wifi

Current Bluetooth devices are supposed to have frequency hopping technology built into them.  However, my Oontz speakers skip when I use the apartment complex WiFi.  Most likely, it is because they are using the same frequency.  Are there any devices that can be used in conjunction with my laptop and/or speakers, that can adjust the Bluetooth channel of the speakers?

Comment: Stuff on the 2.4GHz and 5.8GHz bands don't really operate on a frequency. They operate on "channels" which is either one of many frequency hopping sequence, or modulation codes where the signal spans every frequency simultaneously. You can't choose them. They work it out amongst themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Could be your neighbors are sucking down available bandwidth, not leaving enough space for Bluetooth to do its hopping thing.

Use 5 GHz for your computer if you can. This will free up space on 2.4 for Bluetooth.

There’s a tool from Metageek called inSSIDer that will allow you to see what devices are sharing the Wi-Fi space with you.

Other than that, no. Bluetooth automatically does the best it can to hop-to available channel space. If there’s too much traffic it will fail in the way you describe.

Here’s more of a deep-dive into Bluetooth coexistence: https://internet-access-guide.com/bluetooth-coexistence/

It may be possible to set up the router / AP to improve this. Difficulty: you’d need to convince your landlord IT person.